# pytest using custom options

Tags: python, pytest

I am learning pytest for use in our lab and we use multiple machines with different test configurations. Each machine has it's own conftest file with parameters specific to it's test environment, e.g ipaddresses of test box, etc. Pytest is run from each local machine (`../pytest/cfg/machine1`) which contains its conftest file. The pytest executable is in a remote directory. So the command is:

```
# ../pytest/cfg/machine1 py.test -vs  /dir/path/to/pytest/executable
```

This worked fine until I added a custom option. Now it appears that pytest can no longer find the conftest file in the directory I'm running it from. I found an undocumented option `--confcutdir` which seems to correct the problem.

Is this the best solution and why is this occuring the first place? The pytest documentation is not very clear on why this fails or how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that most likely you need to use pytest-xdist
http://pytest.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.3/xdist.html
it allows you to run tests on remote machines
in your case, it will be not spreading over the machines, but running same tests on all of them
then you can adjust test configuration directly in the hooks/fixtures depending on the actual machine test is running on

This is not direct answer, but a proposition how you could improve your testing and the problem you had initially will not be the case then.

Answer (score 0):

Consider and perhaps try the molecule testing framework:
https://molecule.readthedocs.io/

It's utilizing pytest and testinfra libraries.
I was actually very successfull running the same set of tests against different environments and servers in those environments.
Conftest file could stay the same and you would need just to configure molecule.yml files related to your environments.